# Spark-SQL slow query performance

Tags: apache-spark

Below are configurations:

1. Hadoop-2x (1 master, 2 slaves) 
   yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory = 7096 m
   yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation= 2560 m
2. Spark - 1.5.1
   spark/conf details in all three nodes :
   `spark.driver.memory              4g

   spark.executor.memory            2g

   spark.executor.instances         2`

   `spark-sql>CREATE TABLE demo
   USING org.apache.spark.sql.json
   OPTIONS path`

This path has 32 GB compressed data. It is taking 25 minutes to create table demo. Is there anyway to optimize and bring it down in few minutes? Am I missing something out here?

Answer (score 2):

Most usually each `executor` should represent each core of your CPU. Also note that `master` is the most irrelevant of your all your machines, because it only assigns tasks to `slave`s, which do the actual data processing. Your setup is then correct if your `slave`s are single-core machines but in most cases you would do something like:

```
spark.driver.memory      // this may be the whole memory of your master
spark.executor.instances // sum of all CPU cores that your slaves have
spark.executor.memory    // (sum of all slaves memory) / (executor.instances)
```

That's the easiest formula and will work in vast majority of Spark jobs.